# LINQ 'in' clause for child object properties

Tags: c#, linq

With the following object hierarchy, I need to confirm whether or not all string `Id` values are present in `Inventories` of each `SearchResult` e.g.

Given a `string[] list = { "123", "234", "345" }` confirm all `list` values are present at least once in the array of `Inventory` elements. I'm curious if I can clean this up using one LINQ statement.

```
SearchResult
--
Inventory[] Inventories

Inventory
--
String Id
```

Right now, I'm splitting `list` e.g.

`list.Split(').ToDictionary(i => i.ToString(), i => false)`

And iterating the dictionary, testing each Inventory. Then, I create a new `List<SearchResult>` and add items if there are no false values left in the dictionary. This feels clunky.

### Code

```
// instock: IEnumerable<SearchResult>
foreach (var result in instock)
{
    Dictionary<string, bool> ids = list.Split(',').ToDictionary(i => i.ToString(), i => false);
    foreach (var id in ids)
        if (result.Inventory.Any(i => i.Id == id.Key))
            ids[id.Key] = true;

    if (!ids.Any(i => i.Value == false))
        // instockFiltered: List<SearchResult>
        instockFiltered.Add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bit of code I wrote. The advantage here is that it uses a hash map, so it has theoretically linear complexity.

```
    public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> superset, IEnumerable<T> subset, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<T>(superset, comparer);
        return set.IsSupersetOf(subset);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't even think of this; seems LINQ has a bit of a "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a thumb" effect on people.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of LINQ will iterate over the entire stock and then interrogate the inventory (if it's not null) and find inventory that contain one of the values in your list.

```
var matches = instock.Where(stock => stock.Inventory != null && stock.Inventory.All(i => list.Contains(i.Id));
```

Comment: `instock` is a collection of `SearchResult`. The `Inventory` object defines the `Id` in question.

Comment: Wouldn't this just confirm that *either* of the `Id` values are present? I need to confirm *all* are present.

Comment: My edit didn't take, the `Any` call was supposed to be `All`.